# Dynamically reference data from multiple tabs and sort it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange, sorting, pivot-table

I've got a spreadsheet with multiple tabs of data. The data contains 2 columns, `A` = Categories, `B` = Quantity.

I've created a copy of the spreadsheet [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yajc-q9IYoZnx5R3UWnENVwOxHQjQNjbUF-5zdDZyHw/edit#gid=1383699182) (please use file > copy) if you would like to have a copy of the file to edit.

I want to reference all the data into a "master sheet" and then sort it. But I want the data to be referenced eg. if it changes in the original tab, the "master sheet" should update also.

Currently I've tried doing this 3 ways :

Option 1.
Reference all the data into the master tab using `=Sheetname!B2` and repeat for each sheet. This works to view all the data on one page, but once the data is in it does not allow me to sort it.

Option 2.
Reference all the data into the master tab using `=Sheetname!B2` and repeat for each sheet. Then create a pivot table from the master tab, this works, and allows me to sort, but only sorts the quantity within each category. Not as a full list.

Option 3.
The only way I've got this to work so far, is to do option 1, but then copy the data and paste as values. This works, but is no longer dynamically referenced.

Is there another way I could dynamically reference all the data and then sort it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use curly brackets within this very simple query:

```
=QUERY({Alpha!A2:B;Beta!A2:B;Charlie!A2:B},"select * where Col1 <>'' order by Col2")
```

The trick here is the **curly brackets `{....}`** we use to create and combine the arrays from the different tabs.

**Extra tip**:
**`{Alpha!A2:B;Beta!A2:B;Charlie!A2:B}`**
**A semicolon `;` combines vertically** (in columns, one under the other).

**`{Alpha!A2:B;Beta!A2:B;Charlie!A2:B}</code></pre></b>`**
**A comma `,` combines horizontally** (in rows, one next to the other).

The use of the semicolon and comma **interchange places** depending on your locale.

---

**EDIT** *(following [your comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/134740/dynamically-reference-data-from-multiple-tabs-and-sort-it/134747?noredirect=1#comment123269_134747))*

One can use an additional parameter for `order by`: `order by Col1, Col2`
**Please note that** `order by` defaults to ascending `asc`. That means that it can be omitted (as we did here).
**On the other hand**, descending `desc` must be included (`order by Col1, Col2 desc`)

```
=QUERY({Alpha!A2:B;Beta!A2:B;Charlie!A2:B},"select * where Col1 <>'' order by Col1, Col2")
```

Comment: Thanks @marikamitsos that does exactly what i was looking for. Is there also a parameter that will allow me to change the to sort, by ascending or descending ?

Comment: Ive also updated the google sheet shared in my question to add in your answer in tab "marikamitsos answer"

Comment: _"...a parameter that will allow me to change the to sort, by ascending or descending"_. Ascending which column? The name or the values/numbers?

Comment: The numbers please

Comment: Just found the answer, we can `DESC` to the end of the query. eg. `select * where Col1 <>'' order by Col2 desc`

Comment: Please check my edited answer

Comment: do you know if it is possible to use column letters (eg. colA), rather than column numbers (eg. col1) ?

Comment: No. Not possible. It is either columns by letters (`A, B, C`) or number of column (`Col1, Col2, Col3`)

Comment: Thanks, just tried that but unfortunately could not get it to work, see here : https://imgur.com/a/dEzUKkY

Comment: **Either** letters `A, B, C` **OR** number of column `Col1, Col2, Col3` meaning: **`=QUERY({Alpha!A2:B;Beta!A2:B;Charlie!A2:B},"select * where Col1 <>'' order by Col2 DESC")`**